# Run a script with systemd timers on Nixos

Tags: web-scraping, timer, systemd, nixos

I have a small shellscript `scrape.sh` that scrapes a website and puts the resulting data into a new directory:

```sh
website='test.com'
dir_name="datev_data/$(date -u +'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')"
mkdir $dirname
wget --directory-prefix="$dir_name" "$website"
```

(I don't realy care where the data ends up as long as it is gets a new directory every time and I can get to the data. I therefore put it into my home directory `/home/kaligule` for now.)

Running this script by hand works fine, so now I want to run this script every hour on my nixos-server. Therefore I put the following into my config there (Inspired by [this post](https://christine.website/blog/nixos-discord-webhook-2020-11-30)):

```hs
    systemd.services.test_systemd_timers = {
      serviceConfig.Type = "oneshot";
      script = ''
        echo "Will start scraping now."
        {pkgs.bash}/bin/bash /home/kaligule/scrape.sh
        echo "Done scraping."
      '';
    };

    systemd.timers.test_systemd_timers = {
      wantedBy = [ "timers.target" ];
      partOf = [ "test_systemd_timers.service" ];
      timerConfig.OnCalendar = [ "*-*-* *:00:00" ];
    };
```

Then I test it out:

```
sudo nixos-rebuild switch # everything is fine
sudo systemctl start test_systemd_timers # run it immediatelly for testing
```

I get:

```
Job for test_systemd_timers.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status test_systemd_timers.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

The first suggested command gives me this:

```
● test_systemd_timers.service
     Loaded: loaded (/nix/store/f8348svxpnn6qx08adrv5s7ksc2zy1sk-unit-test_systemd_timers.service/test_systemd_timers.service; linked; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2021-04-02 14:50:02 CEST; 2min 36s ago
TriggeredBy: ● test_systemd_timers.timer
    Process: 5686 ExecStart=/nix/store/4smyxxxlhnnmw8l6l3nnfjyvmg0wxcwh-unit-script-test_systemd_timers-start/bin/test_systemd_timers-start (code=exited, status=127)
   Main PID: 5686 (code=exited, status=127)
         IP: 0B in, 0B out
        CPU: 11ms

Apr 02 14:50:02 regulus systemd[1]: Starting test_systemd_timers.service...
Apr 02 14:50:02 regulus test_systemd_timers-start[5686]: Will start scraping now.
Apr 02 14:50:02 regulus test_systemd_timers-start[5687]: /nix/store/4smyxxxlhnnmw8l6l3nnfjyvmg0wxcwh-unit-script-test_systemd_timers-start/bin/test_systemd_timers-start: line 3: {pkgs.bash}/bin/bash: No such file or directory
Apr 02 14:50:02 regulus systemd[1]: test_systemd_timers.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
Apr 02 14:50:02 regulus systemd[1]: test_systemd_timers.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 02 14:50:02 regulus systemd[1]: Failed to start test_systemd_timers.service.
```

The second suggested command gives me:

```
Apr 02 14:54:42 regulus systemd[1]: Starting test_systemd_timers.service...
░░ Subject: A start job for unit test_systemd_timers.service has begun execution
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit test_systemd_timers.service has begun execution.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 34454.
Apr 02 14:54:42 regulus test_systemd_timers-start[5734]: Will start scraping now.
Apr 02 14:54:42 regulus test_systemd_timers-start[5735]: /nix/store/4smyxxxlhnnmw8l6l3nnfjyvmg0wxcwh-unit-script-test_systemd_timers-start/bin/test_systemd_timers-start: line 3: {pkgs.bash}/bin/bash: No such file or directory
Apr 02 14:54:42 regulus systemd[1]: test_systemd_timers.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
░░ Subject: Unit process exited
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
░░ 
░░ An ExecStart= process belonging to unit test_systemd_timers.service has exited.
░░ 
░░ The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 127.
Apr 02 14:54:42 regulus systemd[1]: test_systemd_timers.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
░░ 
░░ The unit test_systemd_timers.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 02 14:54:42 regulus systemd[1]: Failed to start test_systemd_timers.service.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit test_systemd_timers.service has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit test_systemd_timers.service has finished with a failure.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 34454 and the job result is failed.
Apr 02 14:54:42 regulus sudo[5731]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

So because I got the `Will start scraping now.` in the logs I think the job started but wasn't able to run the script. My questions are:

- where (and with which permissions) should I put my script?
- how should I addapt my config so that the script runs as I described?

(Of course I am thankfull for every feedback to my approach.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that, in your script, `{pkgs.bash}` should be `${pkgs.bash}`; without the `$`, you won't get variable interpolation.

Comment: You are right, I forgot that. The output changed. Thanks a lot.

Comment: For those that come after me: The actual helpfull error message was in the output of the first command, but so far to the right that it didn't show on my 80 char terminal.

Answer (score 4):

On NixOS, systemd services run with a very minimal default environment. You can add the missing packages in [`systemd.services.<name>.path`](https://search.nixos.org/options?channel=20.09&show=systemd.services.%3Cname%3E.path&from=0&size=50&sort=relevance&query=systemd.services.%3Cname%3E)

```
    systemd.services.test_systemd_timers = {
      serviceConfig.Type = "oneshot";
      path = [
        pkgs.wget
        pkgs.gawk
        pkgs.jq
      ];
      script = ''
        echo "Will start scraping now."
        ${pkgs.bash}/bin/bash /home/kaligule/scrape.sh
        echo "Done scraping."
      '';
    };
```